# Date format DD MM YY in Jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to change the date format of shipDate in $("#FIELD_919").val(shipDate); at the moment it displays 2014/08/11 but I want it to display 11/08/2014.

Please have a look at my code.

```
<script src="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jSINI.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='Form_Header_ExtraSpaceAbove'><p class='Form_Header'>Date Required:</p>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width:200px;" readonly="true">

<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf("User") != -1)
{
var varName = "DateRequired";
var today = new Date();
var displayDateRequired=(new Date(today.getTime() + 7*(86400000)))
displayDateRequired=displayDateRequired.format('dddd, d MMMM, yyyy');
$("#FIELD_574").val(displayDateRequired);
var shipDate=(new Date(today.getTime() + 6*(86400000)))
var Weekdays=shipDate.getUTCDay();
if(Weekdays==0||Weekdays==6){
shipDate=(new Date(today.getTime() + 4*(86400000)));
}
shipDate=GetDateFormat(shipDate);
$("#FIELD_919").val(shipDate);


function FormGetFieldValue (fieldName)
{
    return PFSF_GetFieldValueByName("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[fieldName]);
}

function FormSetFieldValue (fieldName, fieldValue)
{
    PFSF_SetControlValue(PFSF_Find('FIELD_' + FieldIDs[fieldName]), fieldValue);
}
function GetDateFormat (shipDate)
{
var shipDate1="";
if((shipDate.getMonth()+1 )>9 && shipDate.getDate()<10) {shipDate1=shipDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (shipDate.getMonth()+1 ) + '/0' + (shipDate.getDate());}

if((shipDate.getMonth()+1 )<10 && shipDate.getDate()>9) {shipDate1=shipDate.getFullYear() + '/0' + (shipDate.getMonth()+1 ) + '/' + (shipDate.getDate());}

if((shipDate.getMonth()+1 )>9 && shipDate.getDate()>9) {shipDate1=shipDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (shipDate.getMonth()+1 ) + '/' + (shipDate.getDate());}

if((shipDate.getMonth()+1 )<10 && shipDate.getDate()<10) {shipDate1=shipDate.getFullYear() + '/0' + (shipDate.getMonth()+1 ) + '/0' + (shipDate.getDate());}

return shipDate1;
}
}


</script>
</div>
```

It will be great if you can help me out with this.

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of jQuery and jQuery UI? And where do you instantiate your datepicker?

Comment: Yes, the code is quite old. I am using it on a .NET portal. There is a shipping step where I calculate date for shipping based on few conditions.